# Trigonometric integrals and limits

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry, fourier-series

Show $$\lim_{N\to\infty}g_N(\theta_N)=2\int^\pi_0\frac{\sin x}{x}dx-\pi,$$
where $$g_N(\theta_N)=\int_0^{\theta_N}\frac{\sin[(N+1/2)x]}{\sin(x/2)}dx-\pi,$$
$$\theta_N=\frac{\pi}{N+1/2},$$
and $$g_N(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{n}-(\pi-x).$$

So far I have: $$\lim_{N\to\infty}g_N(\theta_N)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^{\theta_N}\frac{\sin[(N+1/2)x]}{2\sin(x/2)}dx-\pi$$
Let $u=(N+1/2)x$, and $du=N+1/2$.
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int^\pi_0\frac{\sin(u)\cdot(N+1/2)}{2\sin(\frac{u}{N+1/2})}du$$
But the integral is no simpler than when I started.
How would I go about showing this?

(This question is part of a series of questions demonstrating Gibbs phenomenon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g_N(\theta_N)$ be given by

$$g_N(\theta_N)=\int_0^{\theta_N}\frac{\sin\left((N+1/2)x\right)}{\sin(x/2)}\,dx-\pi$$

where $\theta_N=\pi/(N+1/2)$.  Now, enforcing the substitution $x\to x/(N+1/2)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
g_N(\theta_N)&=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)}\frac{1}{N+1/2}\,dx-\pi\\\\
&=2\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{(2N+1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)}\,dx-\pi
\end{align}$$

Note that for $N\ge1$, we have

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{(2N+1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)}\le \frac{\sin(x)}{x\cos\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)}<\frac{2\sin(x)}{x}$$

Since $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx<\infty$ is integrable, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to \infty}g_N(\theta_N)&=2\int_0^\pi \lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{(2N+1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)}\right)\,dx-\pi\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx-\pi
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Doesn't the Dominated Convergence Theorem only guarantee that it is integrable? And that it is bounded by $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: Oh, but as $N\to\infty$, $\frac{\sin x}{x\cos(x/(2/n+1)}\to\frac{\sin x}{x}$!

Comment: Then wouldn't that just prove that is is bounded by $\frac{\sin u}{x\cos(u/(2N+1))}$?

Comment: @MattG The DCT allows to interchange the limit and integral.